# Linq query builder

Tags: sql, linq

I have a Linq query:

```
from c in table where id = 1
```

but sometimes I need to use just

```
from c in table
```

to recover all records.

Is it possible to do something like the following:

```
From c in table
if (!id == 0)
{
    where id = 1
}
```

or do if have to code it

```
if (!id == 0)
{
    from c in table where id = id
}
else
{
    from c in table 
}
```

Comment: if (id != 0)   not  if (!id == 0)    that can be misleading. And yes, thats exactly the way you should use it (the second try).

Comment: @Seti: the second try doesn't work because he doesn't assign the query to a variable (apart form the missing `select`). Even if it is pseudo-code it's important because i think that OP doesn't know how to asssign the default and what type the variable has.

Comment: This is C#, its typed language so i think it knows the type...

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use:

```
var records = db.table;
if(id != 0)
    records = db.table.Where(r => r.id == id);
```

Due to LINQ's deferred execution the first statement does not query the database.

Since you seem to prefer query syntax:

```
var records = db.table;
if(id != 0)
    records = from rec in db.table
              where rec.id == id
              select rec;
```

Comment: This do works only if table is already `IQueryable<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` (as is probable due to its name), otherwise write `var records = from x in db.table select x;`

Comment: @xanatos: with Linq-To-SQL or Linq-To-Entities that is the case, isn't it?

Comment: Yep :-) (for this reason I wrote *as is probable due to its name*)

Comment: @xanatos: if questions don't mention the LINQ provider it is almost always a database driven providers. All the more with the terms _table_ or _record_ ;)

Comment: Anyway, if db-driven, you want `var`'s compile-time type to be `IQueryable<T>` (not e.g. `DbSet<T>`), so it should probably be `db.table.AsQueryable()`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Tim's reply, what I've seen and used is also to use a "dummy" `where true` expression in cases where no other `where` clause is required, so you can use a single expression:

```
from c in table where id != 0 ? c.Id == id : true select c;
```

I'm not aware of any drawbacks, even if it might look more obfuscating. And of course you need to understand the shorthand expression.

Comment: But this relies on a clever database optimizer, otherwise all records are "filtered" even if you don't want to filter them. It's simply redundant and doesn't make it clearer either.

Comment: Yes Tim, I mean that in case of Entity Framework, the SQL Command is optimized

Comment: Some further expanation Tim: We use some kind of **Specification pattern** to build query expressions in our Project. The specification is a required artifact for the builder and for cases where it's not required, there is a `TrueSpecification` which is basically a `() => true` expression. In our situation, it works well for the EF.